# Algorithm to generate 2 combinations from 1 list

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, combinatorics

I need an algorithm that will generate 2 lists of 3 characters taken from a list of 6. For example I have an array containing `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` and I want to create combinations such as `[a,b,c][d,e,f]`.

I need to get all the possible combinations of 2 times 3 characters.

**Constraint**

- Two combinations can't be the same. What I mean is that I cannot have 2 times the same 3 characters together in a different order. So if `[a,b,c][d,e,f]` was already generated, I can't have `[b,a,c][f,d,e]` as another possibility or `[f,d,e][b,a,c]`.

I would ideally like if the algorithm was in javascript, but I'm open to any other suggestion (I can read code, even if I don't know the language I'll most likely be able to understand the algorithm in a language I don't know). I have looked at a lot of posts and questions about permutations and combinations, but none seem to be what I'm looking for and I can't seem to figure out how to modify them to fit what I'm looking for.

Comment: this sounds an awful lot like a homework question. consider yourself how you can solve this. you have a set with 6 elements. can you sort them? if so, permutations of 3 from a choice of 6 is 120 combinations which isn't extreme. so if you generate a list, then sort it, you can compare to your existing lists and acquire your isomorphic permutations set. (you can optimize this further in a few ways too) edit: you'll have to expand on this idea for the collection of two lists

Comment: I know it sounds like homework but it's more like self-homework. I need to do this to easily generate the teams for a sport schedule where 2 teams will never be the same. I am not required by school or work to do this. It's just that the person in charge of the scheduling is doing it by hand and I was wondering how it would be possible to generate such a schedule automatically to save time. I mostly asked out of curiosity and to get a better understanding of such algorithms.

Comment: Do those two combinations have to contain unique characters? That is, can you have `[a,b,c][c,d,e]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to observe in this question is : **We need not build the second list of three items, once we build the first list of three items, the second list is just complement of first list**.

**Example**:

Suppose we select 3 items as `[a , b , c]`, The second list is simply got as

`[a , b , c , d , e , f]` - `[a , b , c]` = `[d , e , f]`

So we will be focusing only on first list(*list 1*).

Let us focus on any single element, say `a`(*taken arbitrarily*). We observe that:

**Every possible combination will always have `a` as a member of the some list, out of the two lists, and whichever contains `a`, lets call it list 1**.Let us select other members of `list 1`.

We have selected first member. The second member can be selected out of `[b , c , d , e , f]`.

In first iteration of our algorithm, we will select second member as `b`. The third member can have four possibilites. Meaning we have to select one element from `[c , d , e , f]`. Once we select the third member ,our `list 1` is complete and so is `list 2`. The first iteration is complete when the third member has been considered with all 4 possibilities.

In Second iteration of our algorithm, we will select second member as `c`. Now the third member can have only 3 possibilities, and **NOT** 4, because we have already considered b. The three possibilities will be `[d , e , f]`.Once we select the third member ,our `list 1` is complete and so is `list 2`. The second iteration is complete when the third member has been considered with all 3 possibilities.

Similarly,In Third iteration , our second member will be `d`, and we will have 2 possibilites for the third member `[e , f]`.

Similarly,In fourth iteration , our second member will be `e`, and we will have only 1 possibility for the third member which is `f`.

**NOTE**

We need not worry about how many iterations our algorithm will have, the termination condition of our algorithm will be total number of possible combinations which is `6choose3/2` = `10`.

**Data Structures used**

Will we use an array of bits of length 6 `arr`, and for every combination of `list 1`, we place `1` in corresponding positions. Because It will be initialized to 0, so for every 0, it means a member of `list 2`.

Meaning `list 1` = `[a , b , c]`, then `arr` = [1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0]

The pseudocode of our algorithm is as follows:

```
Initialize an array of character of length 6 namely set = [a , b , c , d , e , f]

Initialize an array of integer(or boolean to save space cause we will be storing only 0 
and 1) of length 6 namely arr,initialized to 0.

int x = 10, total = 0,i = 1.
arr[0] = 1// because element a belongs to list 1

while(total < x)
{
 arr[i] = 1

 for(j = i + 1 to 5)
 {
  arr[j] = 1
  list 1 is made of all elements set[k] such that arr[k] = 1
  list 2 is made of all elements set[k] such that arr[k] = 0
  arr[j] = 0
 }

 total = total + 5 - i 
 arr[i] = 0
 i = i + 1
}
```

The pseudocode is simple to follow and should be easy to code.Take that up as an exercise.

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you very much for this very detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

To avoid `[a,b,c]` ⇆ `[a,c,b]` duplicates, pick the first player from "a" to "d", the second player after the first player up to "e", and the third player after the second player up to "f".

To avoid `[a,b,c][d,e,f]` ⇆ `[d,e,f][a,b,c]` duplicates, keep player "a" in the first team.

This is the simplest code to do this: (it picks the people for one team; the second team is then obviously made up of the other 3 people)

```js
function distribute(n) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < 6; j++) {
            document.write("team 1: " + n[0] + ", " + n[i] + ", " + n[j] + "<br>");
        }
    }
}
distribute(["a","b","c","d","e","f"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple:

1. Iterate all 2-subsets of `{2, …, 6}`, e.g. using backtracking.
2. For each subset `S`, consider `H1 = S ⋃ {1}`, `H2 = {1, …, 6} ∖ H1`
3. The current combination consists of the items in `A` given by indices in `H1`, and items in `A` given by indices `H2`

Since this enforces `1 ∈ H1`, you won't obtain repetitions like `[a,b,c][d,e,f]`, `[d,e,f][a,b,c]`.

Since sets have no order, you won't obtain repetitions like `[a,b,c][d,e,f]`, `[b,a,c][f,d,e]`.

Comment: short and concise is the best

Answer (score 0):

Given an input set with elements `{1, …, 6}`, you need to **1.** generate all distinct 3-subsets of `{2, …, 6}` and **2.** compute each subset's intersection (remainder) with the input set:

```js
function* subsets(input, length, start = 0) {
  if (start >= input.length || length < 1) yield [new Set(), new Set(input)];
  else {
    for (let i = start; i <= input.length - length; ++i) {
      let first = input[i];
      for ([subsubset, remainder] of subsets(input, length - 1, i + 1)) {
        subsubset.add(first);
        remainder.delete(first);
        yield [subsubset, remainder];
      }
    }
  }
}

let input = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

for ([subset, remainder] of subsets(input, 3, 1)) {
  console.log([...subset].join(''), [...remainder].join(''));
}
```

This is pretty similar to the algorithm outlined by [@Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37887893/1647737). See also [@Dante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37888761/1647737)'s thorough explanation for why we don't include the first element into our 3-subsets (to prevent doubles, it is included in the remainder!).

If your input elements are not unique, you would need to run above algorithm over the input's indices instead of its values.

If your input's size is bigger than 6, you would need to combine with all subsets of the remainder, too:

```
for ([subset, remainder] of subsets(input, 3, 1)) {
  for ([remainder_subset, _] of subsets([...remainder], 3)) {
    console.log([...subset], [...remainder_subset]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute force solution that I can think of:-

first position can have any one out of 6 options.
second position can have one out of 5
third can have one out of 4.

rest 3 would go in the other list. So basically what needs to be done is :-

keep on generating all the 3 size combinations and put them in a hash map. While generating a new combination check if it exists in map or not. If yes then skip it else add it in the map. Efficient way could be storing the sorted order of the combination.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score -1):

Try combination of tree and queue/stack data structure to achieve such behavior.
Algorithm should be simple related to tree traversing looks like.

Comment: I'll have to read up on the tree data structure, I am not very familiar with it